# Can't change the color: Value of type 'MKAnnotationView' has no member 'pinTintColor'

Tags: swift, annotations, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I'm trying to change to pin color on my map but I can't figure out how to do that using the class MKAnnotationView. I have seen a question  here that is identical to this one but it hasn't been answered properly (i.e. the suggested answer does not work). Here's my code:

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Placemark"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
    
    
    
    
    if annotationView == nil{
        annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.pinTintColor = .green // throws an error (Value of type 'MKAnnotationView' has no member 'pinTintColor') !!
        
        annotationView?.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
        

    }else{
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

what am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: The problem is the following line.  var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your `annotationView` is inferred to be a `MKAnnotationView` and not a `MKPinAnnotationView`. You could try like this instead.

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    let identifier = "Placemark"
    var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: identifier)
    
    if annotationView == nil{
        let newAnnotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        newAnnotationView.canShowCallout = true
        newAnnotationView.pinTintColor = .green
        
        newAnnotationView.leftCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

        return newAnnotationView
    } else {
        annotationView?.annotation = annotation
        
    }

    return annotationView
}
```

Comment: You're right. That was the problem. however, I solved it by defining a new MKPinAnnotationView and using it to access the pin color.

Comment: Great! Good luck!